# Algorithm to swap two indices in a symmetric matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, swap

I am trying for a day now to find an algorithm to swap two indices in a symmetric matrix so that the result is also a symmetric matrix.

Let´s say I have following matrix:

```
0 1 2 3
1 0 4 5
2 4 0 6
3 5 6 0
```

Let´s say I want to swap line 1 and line 3 (where line 0 is the first line). Just swapping results in:

```
0 1 2 3
3 5 6 0
2 4 0 6
1 0 4 5
```

But this matrix is not symmetric anymore. What I really want is following matrix as a result:

```
0 3 2 1
3 0 6 5
2 6 0 4
1 5 4 0
```

But I am not able to find a suitable algorithm. And that really cracks me up, because it looks like in easy task.

**Does anybody know?**

**UPDATE**

Phylogenesis gave a really simple answer and I feel silly that I could not think of it myself. But here is a follow-up task:

Let´s say I store this matrix as a two-dimensional array. And to save memory I do not save the redundant values and I also leave out the diagonal which has always `0` values. My array looks like that:

```
[ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6] ]
```

My goal is to transform that array to:

```
[ [3, 2, 1], [6, 5], [4] ]
```

How can I swap the rows and then the columns in an efficient way using the given array?

Comment: Do you mean "line 1 and line 3" or "element (1,0) and element (3,0)"?

Comment: @Jacob: I mean rows if you will.

Comment: When working with symmetric matrices, it's often easiest to store them as full matrices -- it only wastes a little more than half the space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple!

As you are currently doing, swap row 1 with row 3. Then swap column 1 with column 3.

Comment: Thanks! I feel stupid that I could not think of that myself :) I updated my answer to add a follow-up task. Maybe you can have a look on that as well?